# Shared image open URL on tap

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdksharekit

I'm using   - FBSDKShareKit (4.40.0):
I want to share image on facebook. It should be tappable and should open website just like the Endomondo app does.

[image]
I've tried this code but url covers photo and they are not displayed:

```
    let sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
    sharePhoto.image = someImage

    let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
    content.photos = [sharePhoto];
    content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://facebook.com")!
    FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

How they do that?

Comment: What you are looking at does not seem to be a photo share to begin with - it’s likely just a shared _link_, that has title, description and thumbnail specified via OG meta tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that @04FS is right. It is just an og:image. They send the picture to the server and then generate a page with html meta og tags. (There is a redirect between so it was not obvious for me)

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="202423869273" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="endoapp://workouts" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="333210180" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Endomondo Sports Tracker" />
<meta property="al:android:class" content="com.endomondo.android.EndoSplash" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.endomondo.android" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Endomondo Sports Tracker" />
<meta property="og:type" content="endoapp:workout" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.endomondo.com/users/11394222/workouts/1278713145?country=pl&lang=en&measure=metric" />
<meta property="og:title" content="0.02 km run" />
<meta property="og:description" content="(brak nazwy) ran 0.02 km using Endomondo." />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Endomondo" />
<meta property="og:determiner" content="auto" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.endomondo.com/resources/gfx/image/69040478/06074879f4cd011f6b7b8cfa028e146b/big.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="endoapp:duration" content="38" />
<meta property="endoapp:distance" content="0.02" />
<meta property="endoapp:sport" content="https://www.endomondo.com/facebook/sport/0?country=pl&lang=en&measure=metric" />
<meta property="endoapp:unit" content="km" />
<meta property="endoapp:maxspeed" content="6.4" />
<meta property="endoapp:avgspeed" content="1.5" />
<meta property="endoapp:avg_speed" content="39:16" />
<meta property="endoapp:avg_speed_unit" content="min/km" />
<meta property="endoapp:calories" content="2" />
<meta property="endoapp:route:latitude" content="54.19036" />
<meta property="endoapp:route:longitude" content="16.17868" />
<meta property="endoapp:route:altitude" content="0.01" />
<meta property="endoapp:route:latitude" content="54.19023" />
<meta property="endoapp:route:longitude" content="16.17856" />
<meta property="endoapp:route:altitude" content="0.01" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to share on Facebook

import Social

```
func shareToFb(_ yourImage:UIImage!)

    {
     let facebookURL = URL(string: "fb://")
      if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(facebookURL!)) {
      let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
             vc?.add(yourImage)
                    vc?.setInitialText("Initial text here.")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    let urlStr = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workplace-by-facebook/id944921229?mt=8"
                    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

                    } else {
                        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
                    }
                }


            }
```